# bootstrap modal ruby on rails show several modals

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have RoR project, I have 2 bootstrap modals in my erb view.

```
<%= render 'info' %>
<%= render 'info2' %>
```

_info.html.erb:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Info</button>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Contract 1</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

_info2.html.erb:

```
        <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Contract 1</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And I have item.js:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#myModal2').modal('show');
})
```

And application.js :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require cocoon
//= require angular
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

When I open page via link and press buton to show info, it doesn't work sometimes, just blackout without modal. But often it work correct.
However when I refresh page by F5 it always show 1st modal when I press info button. 
Please help me with that magic.

Comment: what is info button?

Comment: It's button in _info.html.erb.